# Can/Does a node.js app utilise more than 1 core, maybe for networking?

Tags: node.js

So I have a single threaded node app, not trying to run it multi-threaded in a cluster, it's a single threaded node.js app.

For example, on a 2-core machine, If I run only one instance of the app, is the second core wasted, or would node.js utilise it for it's async IO

In reality, I'm just wondering how many instances of the app I should run on a 4 virtual cored EC2 instance, it's a websocket server, so each of these instances will be IO-heavy

Comment: Regardless of whether node can make use of additional cores for its IO, you would want to run one node process for each core, since IO hardly needs any processor time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can run your app across multiple cores although it requires you to utilize core functionality [nodejs cluster](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html)

additionally, to make it easy for you check out [pm2](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/) process manager, I find it extremely easy to use with clustering out of the box

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however that's not what I'm asking, I'm asking whether node utilises 1+ cores on it's own, the JS engine is single-threaded, yet the node process itself could utilise 1+ cores, the question is, does it?

Comment: Cool, I didn't know it was possible to run node on multiple cores.

Comment: Kaan, no, a single node process runs on a single cpu, read the documentation I linked to learn how clustering works in details